# Problems registering a dll

Tags: dll, system

I am trying to register a .dll file but I am getting an error. The .dll is in the SysWOW64 folder, through the command line I then `cd \Windows\SysWOW64` and run the following command `regsvr32 php_sdo.dll`

I then get the following error:

"The module "php_sdo.dll" failed to load.

Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path of debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent.DLL files.

The specified module could not be found"

Comment: Regsvr32.exe should only be used on COM server DLLs.  This is not a COM server.  The error message indicates yet another problem, a required PHP DLL is missing, probably php5ts.dll

Comment: What do I need to do to register DLL files?

Comment: Don't register it.  If you have some kind of problem that makes you think you need to register it then you should describe that problem.  Ask another question, be sure to use the [php] tag.

Comment: Do I just add both php_sdo.dll and php5ts.dll into the SysWOW64 folder then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of failure often occurs when one of the dependency of the DLL one wants to register (which physically means, that the program that attempts to register the DLL internally calls LoadLibrary) is missing. You can have a look at the dependency (tree) of your DLL using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).